# Keeping track of all user/unix files on the system

Tags: linux, files, filesystems

Is there a file which keeps track of all user/unix files on the system? (something like `/etc/passwd` but instead of passwords, for ALL files)?

I guess `.bash_history` is the closest to keeping track of changes on the system? Maybe files under `/`, `/home`, `/share`, or `/root` aren't recorded anywhere? I guess such file will be huge and impractical so maybe just `/home`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a great big file with a periodically updated list of all (or nearly all) of the files on the system; generally it's whatever `locate` or `mlocate` uses, (*e.g.* `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`), depending on your system.

Try this:

```
locate -S
```

The output will vary somewhat.  On my system it instantly shows:

```
Database /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db:
    544,777 directories
    5,310,978 files
    715,024,956 bytes in file names
    188,977,811 bytes used to store database
```

The main use of `locate` is to speedily find files and programs older than a day or so that might be anywhere.  For such tasks it's much faster than `find`, since `locate` only needs to read one database file, rather than the entire directory structure the way `find` does.

See `man locate` or `man mlocate` for more details.